# Why struct "VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR" does not have miss shader member?

Tags: vulkan

struct VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR in vulkan 1.3 is defined as follows:

```c
typedef struct VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR {
    VkStructureType                   sType;
    const void*                       pNext;
    VkRayTracingShaderGroupTypeKHR    type;
    uint32_t                          generalShader;
    uint32_t                          closestHitShader;
    uint32_t                          anyHitShader;
    uint32_t                          intersectionShader;
    const void*                       pShaderGroupCaptureReplayHandle;
} VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR;
```

I don't understand  why struct VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR defines a "uint32_t generalShader" for both "ray generation and miss", but individualy for "closest hit, intersection and any hit"

Vulkan Ray Tracing Pipeline has define a few shader stage: ray generation,miss,closest hit, intersection, any hit.

Comment: Maybe miss shaders aren't part of "shader groups"?

Comment: After I read a lot of articles about "raytracing pipeline lines""shader groups""shader binding tables", I guessed why it was designed this way.

Answer (score 0):

so I put my guess here about why it was designed this way.

The "closestHit, anyHit, intersection" shader stages are collectively referred to as Hit, while the "ray gen, miss, callable" shader stages are collectively referred to as General.

According to the Vulkan specification:

- when the VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR is GENERAL, the shader group can only index one General shader.
- when the VkRayTracingShaderGroupCreateInfoKHR is TRIANGLES_HIT_GROUP or PROCEDURAL_HIT_GROUP, the shader group can index more than one Hit shader.

in short, you can either index one General shader(ray gen, miss, callable) or you can index more than one Hit shader"closestHit, anyHit, intersection" in a single Ray Tracing shader group(depend on the Shader Group Type you set).